# Run SVN repositories under IIS

Tags: windows, svn, iis, iis-7

How to setup `IIS 7.0` to serve `SVN` repositories?

First of all I need to make possible remote users to checkout and web-based viewing isn't really necessary.

I tried to setup `WebSVN` but got no success: can't set parent folder for a number of repositories, can't switch off anonymous access, can't link non-anonymous access and access list.

Are there others products for SVN under IIS? Or it's better to learn how to setup WebSVN properly?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118205/how-can-i-publish-a-subversion-repository-to-a-local-iis

Comment: @Kornel Kisielewicz: No! It's NOT a duplicate. That question is about publishing i.e. deploying i.e uploading. I'm talking about SVN server

Comment: @OrbMan, agreed, this is really programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no server modules for IIS, you can't serve an SVN repository directly from IIS.

Serve a subversion repository through Apache, the built in svnserve, or proxy it via ssh.

Answer (score 4):

There is a commercial solution available named [SVNIsapi](http://www.svnisapi.com/). But I have no idea how well it works because it's too expensive for me to even try out.

But why insist on using IIS? Just install the [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), then configure WebSVN with that - WebSVN also works well with Apache.

Comment: Hi, Stefan. Thanks for tip. Indeed it's really too expensive - I'm looking for free solution. I want to find a SVN solution for IIS because I already use it as primary web server platform (for ASP.NET+ADO.NET) so run Apache on non-standard port and my idea was ti give up on it. But as far as I could understand it isn't possible at this time

Comment: According to a post in a forum I read, SVNIsapi lifted content from an alternative product called Sublime SVN. See my comment here for details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118205/how-can-i-publish-a-subversion-repository-to-a-local-iis/1900125#1900125

Comment: +1, I just set it up on my server and VisualSVN was the single easiest deployment experience I've ever had off of a new product.  Effortless

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need IIS or will Apache work out ok?  Visual SVN Server is a great SVN host and installer for Windows.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Comment: First of all I have already setuped and deployed web server under IIS. Also have Apache2 on port 8080 specially for SVN but want to run only one web server.

Comment: I tried VisualSVN too but got no success how to setup a number of separated repositories and a number of grouped repositories under some folder on the same server. I do this using mod_svn without problems!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is "grouped repositories"?

Comment: Maybe I expressed obscure. I mean that there are a number of repos under one directory, e.g. Group1. I want to mention only it into config without mentioning all subdirs as repos. Because theirs number could be large.

Comment: @abatishchev, with the Visual SVN Server gui you can create any number of repositories you want.  I am not familiar with "grouped repositories" though so can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free server called [RocketSVN](http://www.axosoft.com/rocketsvn), it has no official support anymore though.