# Version control system help for a single developer

Tags: macos, version-control, coldfusion

I'm currently a single developer working with the following.

1. Mac for all computing / code requirements
2. Eclipse / Dreamweaver for code editing
3. Windows Server 2008, CF8 IIS for my dev server

Currently when I develop all my apps, I'm starting to find that I'm really in need of an VCS to manage the code as I'm playing that fun game of simply renaming files with v1, v2 etc but this is becoming a nightmare when I start work the next week as you can probably imagine.

My issue is, I'm not sure where to start, what VCS should I use as I would like to store everything on my local network and as my code writing machine is a Mac, and my dev server is a windows machine I'm not sure what products should I look at for an VCS.

If anyone out there is in a similar position i would love to hear how you have your environment set up so you can manage your code as this is proving to be a bit of a nightmare..

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Source control system for single developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400/source-control-system-for-single-developer)

Comment: Mark, I think this question is not duplicate, for one 2008 is some time ago and dVCS got some traction meanwhile and this question is specific on OSX+Windows cross platform usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same requirement and setup.

I use Visual SVN Server on my dev machine to host all of my repositories. (Windows 2008 R2)

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

I use TortoiseSVN on Windows for general SVN tasks:

http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/

I use AnkhSVN for Visual Studio SVN support:

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

I use the built in SVN command in Mac for general SVN tasks:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

On Mac I also use Versions for a graphical SVN front end:

http://versionsapp.com/

Everything except Versions for Mac in this list is free.

Comment: I will say that Versions is well worth the money.  I love it.

Answer (score 1):

As for the client, you can use the subversive plugin for Eclipse.  Simply go to Help -> Install New Software -> (Select your version of Eclipse) -> Collaboration -> Subversive.  Very easy to use.

There are many, many SVN options for windows.  http://willperone.net/Code/svnserver.php This tutorial refers to TortoiseSVN, but that's just one option of many.  Also consider that running it under IIS may not be desirable (http://stackoverflow.com/q/2165540/684934).

Answer (score 0):

I would sign up for a free hosted SVN service
http://www.atlassian.com/hosted/bitbucket/

And use either a SVN plugin or a Tortise / SmartSVN tool to commit.

Commit your code daily, or whenever you get to a working set. You will have unlimited history etc. Its also great as your happy to delete chunks of code / files when you think they aren't needed, and if you find they are needed later, you can still get them.