# Subversion integration in multi user webapp

Tags: svn, web-applications

I am trying to develop a webapp in which multiple users can login to the system, a number of users (4-5) belong to a group. I wish to integrate SVN in this webapp so that all members of the group can have access to their workspace. The webserver is running IIS with php module and mySQL. I need to know how feasible is this and if it's possible, maybe suggest some web clients for svn or possible solutions. 
Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by integrate, access ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: -1:  (1) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118205/how-can-i-publish-a-subversion-repository-to-a-local-iis .  (2) This is already a viable business model.  See the SVN column at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities#Available_version_control_systems .  (3) svn already has an http interface, so you're reinventing a wheel that's already on the vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for visualsvn.com and there you find an SVN server for Windows guys.